# tab bar icons not perfectly centered when screen changes

Tags: react-native

I have a issue with my costume tab bar and that is when I select other screens icons lose their position a little bit and shift to for example right. for better understanding consider these two images:

you can see this compass icon is not centered perfectly:

[image]

but when I tap on screen this become perfectly centered:

[image]

here's my styles on custom bottom tab bar :

```
const TabComponent = ({label, accessibilityState, onPress}) => {
  const focused = accessibilityState.selected;
  const icon = focused ? ICONS[`${label}Active`] : ICONS[label]

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <View focused={focused} style={[styles.container, focused ? styles.focused : null]}>
        <Image style={styles.icon} source={icon} />
      </View>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 20
  },
  focused: {
    backgroundColor: '#3170FF',
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: 46,
    height: 75,
    position: 'relative',
    bottom: 20
  },
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  }
})
```

and below is my styles on bottom tab itself:

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
      style: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: 23,
        borderTopRightRadius: 23,
        height: 64,
        alignItems: 'center',
      }
    }} >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='home' {...props} />,
        }}/>
...
```

how can I fix this issue? any help would be great.